# How does this circuit double the voltage?

Tags: diodes

Please explain image 2. I don't get working of this circuit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE-SE.  It would help hugely if you used the circuit editor to create a nice clear circuit diagram, if the analysis you have done already was typed, and if you highlighted exactly which bit of the analysis you are struggling with.

Comment: Both C1 and C2 are charged to Vs (the max value, not effective) through its diodes in opposite direction (looking from up to down). So at R2 is sum of this voltages.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect what image 2 is trying to show, is the half cycle where the top of the transformer secondary is more positive than the bottom.

In this case the diode on the left is forward biased (so to a first order acts like a wire), and will charge C2 positively relative to the lower connection.

In the other half cycle, the other diode will conduct, and charge C1 negatively relative to the lower connection.

The result is that C1+C2 will have twice the peak secondary voltage (assuming the time constant of the filter Rload.Ctot >> half cycle period)

Answer (score 2):

The schematic has been redrawn.

[image]

It's consists of a rectifier plus filter capacitor for the positive half wave and another for the negative half wave.

The output voltage is double as the filter capacitors are in series.